# Flask, WTForms - send the whole form using ajax

Tags: ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I am wondering how to send the whole wtform using ajax request (this one does not work):

```
function addReport(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var serializeData = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/reports_list',
            data: serializeData,
            success:function(result){                    
            },
            async: false
            });
    }
```

I have one main form, which includes another:

```
Reports = FieldList(FormField(ReportsForm))
```

The idea is to render the form under form, in case user wants to add another one. In short, it should just copy this underform and clone it, then renders to the main one.

How can I pass the entire form in ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to nest `form` elements. So you only send the innermost form. The validation errors are also not displayed when the form is sent via AJAX.

I think you can follow your approach more easily if you add the necessary form fields by cloning with JavaScript without submit.

The following example breaks the nested forms into fieldsets.
If a fieldset is to be added, the previous one is cloned and the necessary attributes are adapted to the requirements.
When removing, the last one is removed.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms import FieldList, FormField, StringField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

class ReportForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf = False
    title = StringField('Name', [DataRequired()])
    lang = SelectField('Language', choices=[('cpp', 'C++'), ('py', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain Text')])

class ReportsForm(FlaskForm):
    reports = FieldList(FormField(ReportForm), min_entries=1)

@app.route('/reports', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reports():
    form = ReportsForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for report in form.reports.data:
            print(report)
    return render_template('reports.html', **locals())
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Reports</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="my-form" method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {% for subform in form.reports -%} 
        <fieldset name="subform">
            {% for field in subform -%}
            <div>
                {{ field.label() }}
                {{ field() }}
                {% if field.errors -%}
                <ul class="errors">
                    {% for error in field.errors -%}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </ul>
                {% endif -%}
            </div>
            {% endfor -%}
        </fieldset>
        {% endfor -%}
        <button id="btn-less" type="button">Less</button>
        <button id="btn-more" type="button">More</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {

            const btnMore = document.querySelector('#btn-more');
            btnMore.addEventListener('click', function() {
                // Clone the previous fieldset element.
                const subform = document.querySelector('fieldset[name="subform"]:last-of-type');
                const newform = subform.cloneNode(true);

                // Remove possible validation error messages.
                const errors = newform.querySelector('.errors');
                errors && errors.remove();

                // Update the necessary attributes.
                const fields = newform.querySelectorAll('input, select');
                fields.forEach(field => {
                    const attrName = field.name;
                    field.name = field.id = attrName.replace(/^(.*)-([0-9]+)-(\w+)$/g, (...args) => {
                        return [args[1], Number(args[2]) + 1, args[3]].join('-');
                    });
                    field.value = '';

                    const labels = newForm.querySelectorAll(`label[for="${attrName}"]`);
                    labels.forEach(label => label.setAttribute('for', field.id));
                });

                // Add the new fieldset.
                subform.after(newform);
            });

            const btnLess = document.querySelector('#btn-less');
            btnLess.addEventListener('click', function() {
                const subforms = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset[name="subform"]');
                if (subforms.length > 1) {
                    // Remove the last of the fieldset elements.
                    subforms[subforms.length - 1].remove();
                } 
            });

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```